# Connect to Database in JSX File

Tags: javascript, jsx

I'm trying to connect my SqlServer database to a webpage I made in a .jsx file.

```js
import "./singlePost.css"
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function SinglePost() {

  const [foodNow, setRecipe] = useState({Title: '', Ingrediants: '', Recipe: '', Description: '', Rating: ''});
   const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState([]);
  

  const setInput = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    console.log(value);


    setRecipe(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  }

  const fetchData = async () => {
   
    //console.log(foodNow);
    
    const newData = await fetch('/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: foodNow.Title
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    //console.log('I received the result.recordset Browser! Re! Re! Re!');
    //console.log(newData[0]);
    const returnedData = newData.map(newData => ({
      // map newData to myStuff
      Title: newData.Title,
      Ingredients: newData.Ingrediants,
      Recipe: newData.Recipe,
      Description: newData.Description,
      Ratings: newData.Rating
    }));
    setReturnedData(returnedData);
  }

  return (
    <div className="singlePost">
       <div className="singlePostWrapper">
        <input
          name="Title" 
          placeholder="Please Enter The Name Of The Recipe" 
          onChange={setInput}>
        </input>
        <button onClick={()=> fetchData()}>Search</button>
       <img src="https://www.mybakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/lr-0953.jpg" 
       alt="" 
       className="singlePostImg" 
       />
       <h1 className="singlePostTitle">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  
           <div className="singlePostEdit">
           <i className="singlePostIcon fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
           <i className="singlePostIcon fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
           </div>
       </h1> 
       <div className="singlePostInfo">
        <span className="singlePostAuthor">Author: <b>Katrina</b></span>
        <span className="singlePostDate">1 hour ago</span>   
        </div>
        <p >    
          {returnedData.map(myOneData => (<li key={myOneData.Title}> 
          Title: {myOneData.Title}<br /> 
          Ingredients: {myOneData.Ingrediants}<br /> 
          Recipe: {myOneData.Recipe}<br /> 
          Description: {myOneData.Description}<br /> 
          Rating: {myOneData.Rating}</li>))}
        </p>  
             
       </div> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Whenever I try to make an input, I get the following error message:

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using the react develop server `npm start` This server is different from your api. If your api is on another port that's part of the issue. In your url try giving the full URL http://localhost:5000/api whatever your api is listening on. If this is not the case we need info about how your API is setup, which ports both are running on. Also if you have different ports, then you will need to setup CORS headers to call it from react.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what `/api` is relative to your web app, what the code at `/api` is doing, where your DB lives, etc.